# Curve 'anti-correlation' detection

Tags: data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

If I have a data set, what algorithm can I use to detect when one curve moves in clear opposition to the majority of curves? For example:

[image]
At point 15, the purple line moves up in opposition to the red, blue and green lines. At point 33, it moves again in opposition. These values are not normalised. The movements in between I consider noise.

Would this be what is called a 'correlation' of -1?